# How to disallow connection by ip country except one?

Tags: firewall, ufw, ip

I want to disallow incoming connection from all country except one.
I know `https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker` and what files I have to download and allow and select 1 country.

Then how do I then implement this file on ufw?

Comment: is this helpful? https://linuxhint.com/ufw_allow_ufw_deny/ and https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ufw.8.html

Comment: Yes I tried this one but do you mean write ip's one by one?

Comment: you could pare it down I guess [this reference](https://www.xmyip.com/ip-addresses/united--kingdom) indicates particular regions of UK for example and I'm sure similar rules apply in other countries too but I've never tried it.

Comment: would the reverse logic work? ie disallow all then whitelist the one range that you want?

Comment: do you have a router supporting openWRT? If so: https://forum.openwrt.org/t/banip-support-thread/16985  And here is a generated list: https://forum.openwrt.org/t/block-incoming-connection-from-all-ip-of-a-country/13358/4

Comment: ufw is just a front end for iptables. It would be easier to use iptables directly, with ipset, and ACCEPT the desired country, DROP the rest.